# Routes are not working "template does not exist"

Tags: reactjs

just started with React and I have displayed a list of Users that have been created. My users list is currently being displayed on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and I would like to set it up in another url example http://127.0.0.1:8000/users. I have read the documentation but I couldn't manage to figure it out after trying many alternatives. This is my code:

Users.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getUsers } from '../../actions/users';

export class Users extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        users: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getUsers();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h2>Users</h2>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>username</th>
                            <th>first_name</th>
                            <th>last_name</th>
                            <th />
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.users.map(user => (
                            <tr key={user.id}>
                                <td>{user.id}</td>
                                <td>{user.username}</td>
                                <td>{user.first_name}</td>
                                <td>{user.last_name}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    users: state.users.users
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUsers })(Users);
```

Dashboard.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import Users from './Users';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


export default function Dashboard() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Users/>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Header from  "./layout/Header";
import Dashboard from  "./users/Dashboard";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Fragment>
                    <Header />
                    <div className="container">
                        <Dashboard />
                    </div>
                </Fragment> 
            </Provider>     
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use router

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Header from  "./layout/Header";
import Users from  "./users/Users"; //Users component location

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <Header />
                    <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
                </Router> 
            </Provider>     
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: not working, I have tried this as well, don't understand why it is not working

Comment: in your project you use just react or there are some back-end framework? it can be happens when routing managing from back-end

Comment: I use django as well

Comment: that its question for django, you should somewhere pass `/user` route

Comment: I have set an api end point and my react script works on http://127.0.0.1:8000/. Are you sure this is a django issue

Comment: ok I fixed it, it was definitely a django issue. I hade to configure a url to catch all urls. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Check the concept of [React-Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) this should help you to achieve what you want

Regards
Pavan Bhamidipati

Comment: I have checked that